# Android ListView multiple selection

Tags: android-listview, multipleselection

I have a listView which is multiple selection here is the code:

```
public void setItemList() {
    cartListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cartListView);
    cartListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            DataHandler.itemToCart);
    cartListView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

I want to remove the items the will be check then, 
but when ever i check all the items it doesn't remove all the items.
One still remain here is the code:

```
public void onClickRemove(View v){
        SparseBooleanArray menBooleanArray = cartListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(int i = 0; i < cartListView.getCount(); i++)
        {
            if(menBooleanArray.get(i) == true && menBooleanArray.size() > 1) 
            {

                DataHandler.itemToCart.remove(cartListView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (menBooleanArray.get(i) == true && menBooleanArray.size() > 1){
                DataHandler.itemToCart.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

What do i lack?